# Laravel group by belongsto

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a problem I'm not sure how to solve,

I have the following tables

**OrderContents**
id
item_id
total

**Item**
id
category_id

**Category**
id
group_id

**Group**
id

With the following relations

```
orderContent->item()
item->caregory()
category->group()
```

What I need, is to get the total, but `grouped by`
Items, categories, and groups so I have the `Total` value summed by these 3 Models

I know how to achieve the first one

> $total = OrderContent::all([ DB::raw('SUM(total) as total')])->groupBy('item_id')

But what about the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use joins --

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins

```
$total = OrderContent::join('items', 'items.id, '=', 'order_contents.item_id')
              ->join('categories', 'items.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
              ->select([DB::raw('SUM(total) as total')])
              ->groupBy('categories.id');
```

Hope that either does what you want or points you in the right direciton!

Comment: Thanks!! It really will help me :) i was trying to do it with eqger loadongs and i was having no luck.. I'll try this way but it definetilly makes sense